# compatability of datatypes across client and server side(both implemented in different languages) of a SOAP web srvice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am working on SOAP web service(contract first approach, WSDL is in place to define operation parameters and their datatypes). The languages in which client side code is written and server side code is written are different. While working on the same I got below queries. I have searched on the internet but did not get much help.

1. Suppose there is a parameter "param" whose datatype is "XXX". Now range of "XXX" datatype does not match with the range of server side language. Then, what will happen in this case? How the request parameter will be marshaled to server side though the datatype is same but range is different?
2. If client side code is generated in Java using Axis2, what would be the better approach while making the instance of stub class- for each request instance of Stub class should be created or Stub class instance should be created only once throughout the application and all the service calls should be made using that single stub instance?
3. Does the instantiation of stub make any connection with the service prior to actually calling service method? As per my knowledge it does not make any connection till actual service call is made and once the response is received the connection is close (until Http connection timeout). Is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To ensure your WSDL/Service can be consumed by different languages it is important that you make sure that the WSDL conforms with the WSI specification. Download a copy of SOAP UI and run the WSI compliance check. If your WSDL is WSI compliant you will have minimal worries about data type support. Also in all my years I have not been able to declare a datatype that could not be implemented on a server or client.I would also try to steer clear of the Axis project not that it is bad in any way it just seems stagnant and the apache CXF library is very active so maybe look at that.